# Menu button not working on safari desktop and mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu button, which once clicked does some animations and displays the menu using css and javascript. It is working on chrome desktop, but clicking on the menu button has no reaction on chrome mobile, and both safari desktop and mobile. Any ideas what might be happening?

To be specific, it seems safari is having issues opening the menu on both desktop and mobile devices, where chrome cannot open the menu on just mobile devices.

Here is a link to an example I made. http://menu-test-saif.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/
This is just a small example, opening it on chrome desktop will open a blank menu, but you won't be able to close it. But again, the issue is only being opening it on the select devices mentioned above.

Here is a code snippet of the menu.

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="menu__btn">
        <span class="menu__label">MENU</span>
        <div class="menu--hidden">
            <div class="menu__bg-layer menu__bg-layer-2"></div>
            <div class="menu__bg-layer menu__bg-layer-1"></div>
```

Relevant css

```
.menu__btn {
  float:left;
  background: rgb(0,0,0,0.05);
  border:none;
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu__label {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #4287f5;
}
.menu__title {font-size:1.3em;}
.menu__container {
  transition: all 0.4s 0.3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.17,1);
  transform: translateX(-20em);
  padding: 1em;
  color:white;
  font-size:1em;
  top:0;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:left;
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  position:absolute;
}

.menu__list {
  padding:0;
  margin-top:2em;
}

.menu__item {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  color:black;
}

.menu__item:before,
.menu__item:last-child:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:1px;
  background: hsla(0,0%,100%,1);
  margin: 1em 0;
}

/* #fcba03 */
.menu__bg-layer {
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
  border-radius:50%;
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #4287f5;
  height:0;
  width:0;
}

.menu__btn:focus .menu__container {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition-delay:0;
  width:100%;
  heigth:100%;
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
}

.menu__btn:focus .menu__bg-layer {
  padding-bottom: 250%;
  width:250%;
  opacity:1;
}

.menu__btn:focus .menu__bg-layer-2 {
  background: rgb(0,0,0);
}

.menu__btn:focus .menu__bg-layer-1 {
  transition-delay:0.2s;
}
```

Here is some of javascript, I'm using a template found online, so I don't believe these are actually being used on the menu button its self. But I'll post it in case it might be relevant.

```
var $menu = $('.menu-list'),
    $item = $('.menu-list-item'),
    w = $(window).width(),
    h = $(window).height();

$(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var offsetX = 0.5 - e.pageX / w,
      offsetY = 0.5 - e.pageY / h,
      dy = e.pageY - h / 2,
      dx = e.pageX - w / 2,
      theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx),
      angle = theta * 180 / Math.PI - 90,
      offsetPoster = $menu.data('offset'),
      transformPoster = 'translate3d(0, ' + -offsetX * offsetPoster + 'px, 0) rotateX(' + (-offsetY * offsetPoster) + 'deg) rotateY(' + (offsetX * (offsetPoster * 2)) + 'deg)';

  if (angle < 0) {
    angle = angle + 360;
  }

  $menu.css('transform', transformPoster);

  $item.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        offsetLayer = $this.data('offset') || 0,
        transformLayer = 'translate3d(' + offsetX * offsetLayer + 'px, ' + offsetY * offsetLayer + 'px, 20px)';
    $this.css('transform', transformLayer);
  })
})
```

Comment: i see only html here. Where are js and css? Also what have you tried to debug?

Comment: ah sorry, i've updated my question with that info. I've tried changing cursors, trying different tags <a> and such. I found online that safari has trouble registering click events, but i've tried some and they didn't change anything. Not sure what approach to take.

Comment: Have you tried to change heigth:100%; to height: 100% where .menu__btn:focus .menu__container is?

Comment: Lol that's a typo, thanks for pointing that out. But that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: If it is just by opening and closing the menu button with the blue circle that I see it on my PC Chrome and Firefox and on my mobile on Chrome when I touch the button, it opens and closes without any issue. Maybe something else is the problem there with your installation of the browsers. Check that or please be more specific with your question

Comment: Yeah its working on chrome and firefox pc, but safari seems to be the issue. But yes my main issue, is not being able to open the menu button, specifically in safari. For chrome mobile, did you try it through the desktop version, by seeing it in tablet/phone mode on developer tools? Because for me it actually works there, but trying it on my actual phone doesn't work after deploying my website.

Comment: I've added a link to a menu example I made, trying it on safari desktop, and mobile browsers are yielding my issue.

Comment: Actually I've tried on my mobile phone and even on my tablet and it works OK. I don't have Safari though.